# How to loop my node.name on list/index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, link-to

On one tutorial, I know some link_to code like this.

```
lists/index.html.erb

<ul class="lists box">
<% lists.each do |list| %>
    <li>
        <h2 class="list_title">
            <%= link_to list.title, list %>
        </h2>
        <p>
          <%= truncate(list.content, length: 99) %>
          <br>
          <%= link_to list.node.name, list.node, class: "node" %>
        </p>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

and 2 tables

```
  create_table "lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "node_id"
  end

  create_table "nodes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "summary"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

2 models

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lists
end

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :node 
end
```

controllers is also OK

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @lists = List.all.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(15)
  end

  def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end
.
.
.
  private
    def set_list
      @list = List.find(params[:id])
    end

    def list_params
      params.require(:list).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

another controller

```
class NodesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_node, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :node_list]


  def index
    @nodes = Node.all
  end

  def show
    @node = Node.find(params[:id])
  end
.
.
.
.
```

my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :lists, only: [:index, :show, :new]
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  resources :nodes, only: [:show] 

  root 'lists#index'
end
```

When I rails s , I got error

```
NoMethodError in Lists#index
Showing /Users/zhangxiaodong/workspace/listlist/app/views/lists/_list_list.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

and when I change the link_to 
`<%= link_to list.node.name, list.node, class: "node" %>` to `<%= link_to "list.node.name", list.node, class: "node" %>`
The page is no error ,but the node.name link loop not on the page. 
I look API link_to [http://api.rubyonrails.org/] ,no work, can you tell me how loop my node .

Comment: Can you show your `routes.rb` file contents ?

Comment: thanks, I edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lists/index.html.erb` should look like the following:

```
<ul class="lists box">
  <% lists.each do |list| %>
    <li>
      <h2 class="list_title">
        <%= link_to list.title, list_path(list) %>
      </h2>
      <p>
        <%= truncate(list.content, length: 99) %>
      <br>
        <%= link_to list.node.name, node_path(list.node), class: "node" if list.node.present? %>
     </p>
   </li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `list` may not have any `node`. Just modify the code a bit like this

**Old code**

```
<%= link_to list.node.name, list.node, class: "node" %>
```

**New code**

```
<% if list.node %>
  <%= link_to list.node.name, list.node, class: "node" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

lists/index.html.erb

```
<ul class="lists box">
<% @lists.each do |list| %>
    <li>
        <h2 class="list_title">
            <%= link_to list.title, list_path(list) %>
        </h2>
        <p>
          <%= truncate(list.content, length: 99) %>
          <br>
          <%= link_to list.node.name, node_path(list.node), class: "node" %>
        </p>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```